# How to record number of event occurances to machine in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm after some advice on the best way to approach a database design. We currently have a database that records every event against a machine.

Columns are uid, machine_id, event_id. Every event just gets entered into the database, meaning there are a huge amount of records! As multiple events (events can happen multiple times or not at all) can be entered for a machine_id on any day.

I've tried setting up a database of:
uid, machine_id, event_id, hits 
And setting the machine_id and event_id as a unique index, and then doing a REPLACE INTO rather that an insert - but i then get an issue with not being able to update the hits because i can't do a hits = hits + 1.

All I'm trying to do is come up with the most stream lined way of holding the data i need so that i can pull a count of how many event_ids occur per machine. Any suggestions or help is hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSERT` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO events (machine_id, event_id, hits)
VALUES (:machine_id, :event_id, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = hits + 1
```

Comment: That's so simple and exactly what i was trying to do, thanks so much.